# Had interview for Internship - Interviewing Manager seems to be busy

Tags: recruitment, internship, manager, follow-up

Two weeks ago I had an interview for an internship at a local software company.  I thought the interview went well, and the managers that interviewed me said I would likely hear back from them within a week.  However, there has been a disaster near me, and one of the managers has been extremely busy volunteering for causes related to that.

I'm wondering if I should contact the recruiter and ask what is the status of hiring.  Currently, on the company's career management website, it still displays my application for that position as open.  The manager in question is active on social media, discussing his volunteering.  I understand he does good work, and I applaud him for it, I'm just wondering if there is going to be an internship at all given that there's only 4-5 weeks left of 'summer' for this position.

Given the company's e-mail structure, I could also likely e-mail the manager.  I feel like I should follow up but I'm not quite sure how to go about this.  I'd like to know whether or not I have the position so I can plan the rest of my summer accordingly, rather than wait for the off-chance I might be hired.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no harm in asking. If you went in for an interview, they should have no hesitation telling you where you stand with regards to the hiring process. And if you need internships to graduate, they should be professional enough to provide you with a prompt response so you can make decisions with regards to other internship opportunities. (In other words, you should point out to them the relative urgency with which you need a reply.)

Answer (score 3):

Usually not contacting you in the agreed timeframe is not a great sign. However:

1. They told you that you would hear from them.
2. There is an extreme circumstance right now.
3. Whatever the answer, you will plan your time accordingly.

For these reasons you should contact them about that status. You should not be worried that an e-mail will reach the manager. Your follow-up actually shows interest.